# Http failure during parsing for json file Angular 5 ngx-translate

Tags: json, http, ionic3, angular5

[image]

I want to use ngx translate module but suddenly it started giving this error:

**Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8100/assets/i18n/en.json**

I dont know why. All the libraries are included and the function was working normally for 1-2 lines, but when i added more data in json files **(en.json and ru.json)** it gives this error when I press for translate and of course it does not translate.

**ru.json**

```
{
"User Settings": "Настройки юзера",
"Language": "Язык",
"Englsh": "Английский", 
}
```

**en.json**

```
{
"User Settings": "User Settings",
"Language": "Language",
"Englsh": "Englsh", 
}
```

**page.ts**

```
{
translate.setDefaultLang("en");
//code
this.translate.use(lang); 
}
```

**Error**
 **Http: failure during parsing for http:// localhost:8100/assets/i18n/en.json**

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Your json-files are not correct.
There should be no comma (,) before the closing bracket (})

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for HttpLoaderFactory:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

and also in your angular.json add i18n folder:

```
"assets": ["src/assets",
           "src/assets/i18n"
          ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, baseHref: string) {
  if (baseHref === null && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    baseHref = window.location.origin;
  }
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `${baseHref}/assets/i18n/`, '.json');
}
```

it's working for me